# React Select Control

Tags: reactjs, react-select, react-context

I have data in a file named `GlobalState.js` and I am trying to access it another file named `AddClass.js`.

**GlobalState.js**

```
myclasses:[
     {
      "id":"class1",
      "name":"Maths",
      "students":["arun1","ashok1","rajesh1","mahesh1"],
      "teachers":["ramesh1","suresh1","ashwin1"]
     },
     {
      "id":"class2",
      "name":"Science",
      "students":["arun2","ashok2","rajesh2","mahesh2"],
      "teachers":["ramesh2","suresh2","ashwin2"]
    }
   ]
```

I want the students names to be shown on my React-Select control. Below is the code that I tried. Thank you for the support.

**AddClass.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react'
import { GlobalContext } from '../../context/GlobalState'
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Select from 'react-select'

const AddClass = () => {
    const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState();
    const { addClass, myclasses} = useContext(GlobalContext);
    const studOptions = myclasses.map((c)=> {
        return {label:c.students.map((s)=>{
            console.log("s",s)
            return([{value: s, label:s}]);
        }), value:c.id}
    })

    return (
        <React.Fragment>                                
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>                                                                          
              <label>Select Students</label>                                  
              <Select        
                  value={selectedOption}
                  isMulti
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  options={filteredStud}                              
              />                                                                     
            </form>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default AddClass
```

Comment: What's the error? Probably a good idea to show your `GlobalContext.Provider` as well.

Comment: All students in one select ?

Comment: Not really, each students should be selected on click, anyhow you ppl helped me with the answers which worked for me.. Thank you all.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all the students in all classes and put them to one select options, your code should do something like below:

```
const options = myclasses.map(c => c.students).flat().map(s => ({ label: s, value: s}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make studOptions a state, extract data from myclasses to populate into studOptions, then display it into the select.
Sample: https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-liskov-5k6l4?file=/src/App.js